# How to implement gallery when data(Images and audio path) are coming from server, with swipe on it?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have implemented gallery which is showing only images right now,but i have to display both images and audio files having swipe option on it.On swipe it has to show next image/audio,all the data(image/audio path) are coming from server.Any example or code is much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: yes i have tried but only with images not with audio files..swipe i have not implemented yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve it :

1 : Create a simple ViewPager and set adapter which will contain a view and your audio file.
-http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

2. Use Lazy loading for image and download audio file in your sd-card and show loader on view while its loading.

-https://github.com/novoda/image-loader

-https://github.com/wuman/AndroidImageLoader

If below link is help ful then you can use it.

https://github.com/Trinea/android-common

for download audio file :

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/29/download-file-android-device-remote-server-custom-progressbar-showing-progress/

3. After download audio file you can play it.
4. And please mention a check to download only undownloaded audio.

Comment: for audio files im doing like this: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/29/download-file-android-device-remote-server-custom-progressbar-showing-progress/                                      but how to do the same with images just like whatsapp is using...if we click an image and swipe on it it will load next image or audio,,i want to implement like that.

Comment: its okay No issue if my ans was help full then please mark as right fro other also.